# Why is there this ringed artifact in the render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics, artifacts

This is in Cycles, sample count doesn't seem to affect anything.

I have 2 volume cubes, the rings only appear when both are enabled.

[image]

It only appears in the render, not the viewport. There is nothing in the compositor.

[image]

One of the volume cubes has variable density with a gradient texture and curves.

[image]

I tried all combinations of volume sampling and interpolation - no differences. I also experimented with the step rate and still nothing.

[Blend File](https://www.mediafire.com/file/hj9a750d3992xmg/Impression%252C_Sunrise.blend/file)

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: The blend file is included now